# bt_navigator failing with error `Action server failed while executing action callback: "send_goal failed"`

Tags: slam, navigation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using

- ROS2 Foxy
- Nav2 for navigation
- Slam-toolbox for mapping and localization
- create_robot for odom

When I send a command to the ActionService `navigate_to_pose` from Nav2, most of the time `bt_navigator` will fail with the error:

`[bt_navigator-9] [ERROR] [1627933160.614862066] [bt_navigator]: Action server failed while executing action callback: "send_goal failed"`

`[bt_navigator-9] [WARN] [1627933160.615170308] [bt_navigator]: [navigate_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.`

As far as I can tell, I am calling the Service correctly and my issue might be with my configuration.
My config for nav2 can be found here: https://pastebin.com/KkRUAB5s

I have also thrown all logs from this specific run into a pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/Rx1ZMUeg
the error in question can be found on lines 428 & 429

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383678/bt_navigator-failing-with-error-%60action-server-failed-while-executing-action-callback:-%22send_goal-failed%22%60/) by [jacobwaller](https://answers.ros.org/users/73734/jacobwaller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-08-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2272#issuecomment-880879354, best solution would be to switch from Foxy to Galactic, this solved issue for me.

---

Originally posted by [Serafadam](https://answers.ros.org/users/52568/serafadam/) with karma: 170 on 2021-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2